# Migrate Hibernate 3.3.0 to 5.2

Tags: hibernate, migrate

I need to migrate hibernate 3 to hibernate 5, but I am having many errors.

I changed the version of hibernate-validator and the hibernate-core, and presented errors with classes org.hibernate.validator.Validator and org.hibernate.validator.ValidatorClass.

In version 5 of hibernate, where are these classes?

Follows below part of the pom.xml

```
<!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.SP1</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency> -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator`, there is no base class for annotation anymore.

[migration guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/migration_guide/migrate_to_hibernate_validator_41)